# Why is Acqui Terme not called Acque Terme?

Tags: gender, toponyms

Why is [this](https://www.google.com/maps/place/15011+Acqui+Terme,+Province+of+Alessandria,+Italy/@44.6761109,8.3904619,12z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x12d2d547a8955651:0x808937f19eb91475!8m2!3d44.6763846!4d8.4670285) not "Acque Terme"?

[image: Acqui Terme on a map]

Comment: Why would it be “Acque Terme”?

Comment: The attribute “Terme” has been added to the preexisting toponym of several towns as a form of advertising: Abano, Montecatini, Equi, Boario and so on. This happened also to German places which added “Bad” in front of their name (Bad Kissingen, Bad Pyrmont, Bad Godesberg,…).

Comment: Ricardo answered why it doesn’t follow the expected grammar rule.  In normal contemporary language, the ‘i’ ending is masculine plural and the ‘e’ is feminine plural.

Comment: @WGroleau: You seem to generalise from the nouns corresponding more or less to the first to Latin declensions. This is not the case, but there actually are feminine plurals in _-i_ (_reti_, _chiavi_, _fasi_, _travi_ and many more feminine terms with a singular in _-e_, mostly from third-declension Latin words).

Comment: As a Spanish speaker, I realize there are many exceptions, but I was using the majority for my generalization.  One can't learn the exceptions without asking (or digging in dictionaries).  Especially if one doesn't speak Latin.  :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the website of the town http://comune.acquiterme.al.it/la-citta/noticia/la-storia-del-comune-di-acqui-terme, it was founded by Romans on the II century B.C. and the latin name was  *Aquae Statiellae*.

From late antiquity it appears as *Acquis* that in vernacular will become then *Acqui*. This means that *Acqui* is not a different gender but a different latin case.

The second term "Terme" was added officially in 1956.

Answer (score 5):

You got an excellent answer already, but I would like to point out more explicitly that in *Acqui Terme* the word *Terme* is not something that needs to agree with the name of the town, but rather a modifier that indicates the presence of thermal baths near the city.

This is in fact a relatively common phenomenon. Let me show you some examples

- [Jesolo Lido](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lido_di_Jesolo)
- [Eraclea Mare](https://www.google.com/maps/place/30020+Eraclea+Mare+Metropolitan+City+of+Venice,+Italy/@45.5485219,12.7543352,15z/data=!4m13!1m7!3m6!1s0x477bfc212a85eead:0xd000b2e2bcd356cc!2s30020+Eraclea,+Metropolitan+City+of+Venice,+Italy!3b1!8m2!3d45.5808511!4d12.6801548!3m4!1s0x477bf9be53f1948d:0xa6c18f9bb87094f6!8m2!3d45.5513232!4d12.7686882)
- [Latina Scalo](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latina_Scalo) (thanks to @DaG for this one!)
- [Arquà Petrarca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arqu%C3%A0_Petrarca)

In the first two cases, this is also to advertise that the town is in a different location than the "main" town of the same name, and specifically on the beach front (*Lido* meaning *coast* and *Mare* meaning *Sea*). In the nearby coast you can see several more examples of this.

Comment: Great answer. I'd add, as modifiers to “main names”, _Scalo_ too (as in Orte Scalo or Latina Scalo, where the railway station is not close to the town itself).

Comment: Many towns and villages changed their name after the unification of Italy in order to distinguish them; for instance the two ‘Arquata’ became ‘Arquata Scrivia’ and ‘Arquata del Tronto’ and, most notably, the two ‘Reggio’ became ‘Reggio nell'Emilia’ and ‘Reggio di Calabria’. Other additions were made to honor important citizens: the cited ‘Arquà Petrarca’ for Francesco Petrarca who lived in the village in his last years and is buried there; also ‘Sasso Marconi’ for Guglielmo Marconi and ‘Riese Pio X’ for the pope who was born there.

Comment: Let's not forget about [Anticoli Corrado](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anticoli_Corrado)! :D